# Python: If dataframe column matches dictionary key then return boolean for new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm having difficulties trying to get this to work.  So to summarize: I have a dataframe, I have a dictionary with keys of certain values in a certain dataframe value, and I want to create a new dataframe column of true/false if they match or not.

So here is an example of the data:

```
animal_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird', 'dog', 'bug', 'bird', 'snake']
animal_dict = {'dog': [3], 'bird': [2]}

animals = pd.DataFrame(animal_list, columns = ['Pets'])
animals
```

[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Qlv.png)

Basically I want a new column with boolean True if it matches the key, or False if not.

ALTERNATIVELY I suppose I could skip the dictionary altogether if I could create the new column with a query on if there are multiple instances of a value in existing column ('Pets').  So it would be True for dogs and birds, but false for everything else.

UPDATE:  Here is the solution I used, for others who may be searching for it.  I originally had this function but was using apply method instead of map (as suggested by algebruh below)

```
def find_key(find_value):
    for k, v in animal_dict.items():
        if k == find_value:
            return True
    return False

animals['multiple'] = animals['Pets'].map(find_key)
```

Comment: you can use `animal.map(f)` to call a function `f` on every single value in a dataframe and collect the results  in a new dataframe. In order to check that a string `s` is a key in a dict you can write `s in animals_dict`

Comment: Well, I did have a function for my actual dataset but I was using .apply(), so .map() does work now.  I'm only interested in matching values of a column and not the entire dataframe but that's simple enough.  I'll update OP with the solution for others.

Comment: what also seems to work is: `animal.apply({"Pets": lambda x : x in animal_dict})`. In this case you only apply it to the target column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if `animals['Pets']` [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) `animals_dict`:

```
animals['multiple'] = animals['Pets'].isin(animal_dict)
```

Output:

```
    Pets  multiple
0    dog      True
1    cat     False
2    dog      True
3   fish     False
4   bird      True
5    dog      True
6    bug     False
7   bird      True
8  snake     False
```

Comment: Yes this works too.  I remembered doing something like this in the past but couldn't remember it exactly.  Still wanted to know how to do this from a dictionary though, for reasons.  Also in my actual dataset I am using 0 and 1s so I can do SMOTE augmentation.

Comment: @BeaverFever sounds like you should post a question with a snippet of your actual dataset; there may be optimisations possible with the actual data too.